# How can I surface TFS 2010 project associated Information with SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tfs

How can I surface TFS 2010 project associated Information with  SharePoint2010, i.e. work items etc. from TFS.

Has anyone surfaced that data in SP 2010 so that the users can access all that info from their team portal? Are there any neat web parts that will let you do that?

Would BCS be requried to surface data from TFS?!
Any insights/thoughts/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have a whole set of TFS webparts that you can deploy and activate in SP2010. They come with the TFS installation files.

See [Extensions for SharePoint Products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552177.aspx) or [Add Integration with SharePoint Products to a Deployment of Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462861.aspx)

And this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVlEe9lDmP8) for a visual overview of what they provide.